# How to add or update css file in PHPFOX

Tags: php, html, css, phpfox

I am trying to update existing css file but file is not updating, seems phpfox is generating cache. Then I tried to add another css file in template.html.php using following code..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{param var='core.path'}theme/frontend/freedawn/style/default/css/cus_style.css" />
```

Html file gets updated but displays error "**CSS file not found.**"

How to add/ update css/js file in PHPFox?

Answer (score 0):

set version number at the end of file for getting a current version.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clear the cache in Maintenance / Cache Manager? If you modified controller and assets, such as CSS, most probably site will display old cached data and you won't be able to locate your changes.